# Is there a name for rings that have non-trivial idempotent elements ($a^2=a$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there a name for rings that have non-trivial idempotent elements ($a^2=a$)?

This question arises from the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844658/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-ring-morphism-a-times-a-to-b-from-a-ring-morph/3844670) post.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, if $a^2=a$, then $a(a-1)=0$ and so the ring has zero divisors.

Comment: Elements that satisfy the property $a^2 = a$ are called idempotents. Also @Wuestenfux not necessarily, because $a-1$ could be equal to $0$. I suppose it depends on whether or not OP means that all elements satisfy $a^2 = a$, as in that our ring is a boolean ring (which do have zero divisors), or if we're just talking about a single element, in which case we can't make that conclusion.

Comment: @SeraPhim I see, thank you. Just that there exist, I will update question.

Comment: Very often they are called "*Rings with non-trivial idempotent*" Such a non-trivial element is a zero divisor.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see, I guess it's not something very useful so we don't have a name for it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see, thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidCheng Please don't put the question only in the title. It is perfectly fine (advisable even) to have it in both the title and the body.  I edited it in for you this time.

Comment: @rschwieb Got it, thanks.

Comment: See also [Examples of rings with idempotent elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/examples-of-rings-with-idempotent-elements/6052#6052)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word for a ring with only trivial central idempotents was introduced at the post you linked: **directly irreducible ring**.

In general it is a bad idea to introduce a new term for the negation of a definition. In this case, the best way to describe it is “directly reducible ring.”

There is another important term to know: a commutative ring with only trivial idempotents is called **connected**.  This is related to the topology of its spectrum of prime ideals.

I am not aware of a common term for a (possibly not commutative) ring with only trivial idempotents.  Usually people just say "a ring with only trivial idempotents."  Domains and local rings are large classes of examples, but there are examples that are neither domains nor local, such as $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-1)$.

Of course, there are many examples of rings which are directly irreducible but have nontrivial idempotents. $M_n(F)$ for any field $F$ and $n>1$ would be an example.